# to_date fails to parse date in Spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark3

I am trying to parse date using `to_date()` but I get the following exception.

> SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse '12/1/2010 8:26' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.

The exception suggests I should use a legacy Time Parser, for starter I don't know how to set it to Legacy.

Here is my implementation

```
dfWithDate = df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("InvoiceDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

my date is in following format

```
+--------------+
|   InvoiceDate|
+--------------+
|12/1/2010 8:26|
|12/1/2010 8:26|
|12/1/2010 8:26|
|12/1/2010 8:26|
|12/1/2010 8:26|
```

Answer (score 39):

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("InvoiceDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy")).show()


+--------------+----------+
|   InvoiceDate|      date|
+--------------+----------+
|12/1/2010 8:26|2010-12-01|
+--------------+----------+

# in above code spark refers SparkSession
```

Comment: Can the same date be parsed without using legacy parser policy ?

Answer (score 13):

You can keep using the new implementation of spark 3 by parsing the string into timestamp first, than cast into a date :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dfWithDate = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.to_timestamp(col("InvoiceDate"), "M/d/yyyy H:mm")))

dfWithDate.show()
#+--------------+----------+
#|   InvoiceDate|      date|
#+--------------+----------+
#| 2/1/2010 8:26|2010-02-01|
#| 2/1/2010 8:26|2010-02-01|
#| 2/1/2010 8:26|2010-02-01|
#| 2/1/2010 8:26|2010-02-01|
#|12/1/2010 8:26|2010-12-01|
#+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) in spark 3 you should use pattern `"M/d/y"`. It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

in case you want to keep using the Spark 3.0 version (not use the legacy version of time conversion), you can just use one digit of `d` in `"MM/d/yyyy"`:

```
dfWithDate = df.withColumn("date", to_date(col("InvoiceDate"), "MM/d/yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the legacy parser you could also update the date format from MM/dd/yyyy to MM-dd-yyyy

> This is not a solution as it returns in NULL values

Answer (score 1):

One can use:

```
data = data.withColumn("Date", to_date(unix_timestamp("InvoiceDate", "MM/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))

#result
    +--------------+----------+
    |   InvoiceDate|      Date|
    +--------------+----------+
    |12/1/2010 8:26|2010-12-01|
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the legacy parser you could also update the date format from MM/dd/yyyy to M-d-yy. It worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).