# Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.0 DateTime question of date time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Right I am on a new environment upgraded from Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.0 and I am receiving these errors

ERROR 1
You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to recognize 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa' pattern in the DateTimeFormatter
Lines causing this –
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(powerappcapturetime_local, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa')+ (timezoneoffset*60),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as powerappcapturetime

ERROR 2
DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 94.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 94.0 (TID 1203) (10.139.64.43 executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse ' 01/19/2022' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeFormatterHelper$$anonfun$checkParsedDiff$1.applyOrElse(DateTimeFormatterHelper.scala:141)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.Iso8601TimestampFormatter.$anonfun$parse$1(TimestampFormatter.scala:86)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)”
Lines causing this –
cast ( to_date ( TT_VALID_FROM_TEXT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp) as ttvalidfrom

My code is python with sql in the middle of it.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")

query_view_create = '''

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {0}.{1} as

SELECT
customername
,
cast ( to_date ( TT_VALID_FROM_TEXT, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp)
as ttvalidfrom
, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(powerappcapturetime_local, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa')+ (timezoneoffset*60),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')  as powerappcapturetime
from {0}.{2}
'''.format(DATABASE_NAME,VIEW_NAME_10,TABLE_NAME_12,ENVIRONMENT)
print(query_view_create)

## Added to fix datetime issues we see when using spark 3.0 with Power BI that don't appear in spark 2.4

spark.sql(query_view_create)

The error still comes from Power BI when I import the table into Power BI . Not sure what I can do to make this work and not display these errors ?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/timestamp-conversion.html Check the link for conversion. Kindly revert back if any troubleshoot needed.

Comment: Cluster never had legacy settign switched on was the problem . Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@James Khan**, Thanks for finding the source of the problem. Posting your discussion as an Answer to help other community members.

To set the legacy timeParserPolicy the below code may work.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")
```

**OR**

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")
```

Still If you are getting the same after this, please check this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943941/to-date-fails-to-parse-date-in-spark-3-0).

**Reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/parameters/legacy_time_parser_policy